# MVC client can't authenticate on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver3, iis-8.5

I've succeeded with IdentityServer3 implementation. I created ASP.NET MVC5 client with implicit flow and this Owin startup configuration:

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    { AuthenticationType = "Cookies" });

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
       ClientId = "mvc.client",
       Authority = Constants.ServerUri,
       RedirectUri = Constants.MvcClientUri,
       ResponseType = "id_token",
       Scope = "openid profile",
       UseTokenLifetime = false,
       SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

       Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
         { SecurityTokenValidated = TokenValidatedNotification },
        });
```

Everything works perfect running locally on IIS Express, but fails when deployed to production IIS server. Authentication is successful in both cases - `id_token` is returned from then same IdentityServer, but on production user is never authenticated, notification is not fired. Project references `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` assembly. I've registered exception handling `OwinMiddleware` as first one, but no unhandled exception was catched.

Comment: Have you tried AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie?

Comment: I've tried but with no change - works locally, not authenticated at production

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the production IIS has the website configured to use `Anonymous` authentication, as you are not relying on IIS's authentication infrastructure, you want the request to flow through IIS and get to the OWIN middleware responsible for authentication.

Comment: Only `Anonymous` is allowed. What settings do you mean by _IIS's authentication infrastructure_?

Comment: IIS has it's own authentication mechanisms, but when you are using OWIN and authenticate the users at the application level (using a `middleware`) you want IIS to skip auth processing. If you say that IIS is already configured with only the `Anonymous` option, then the problem is not comming from there.